# Проблема с vue.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всех приветствую, есть такая проблема в vue.config.js, я подключаюсь к бэкенду через прокси и проблема в том , когда у меня 2 бэкенда то я могу использовать прокси только для одного сервера, потому что у меня почему то работает только с ключем '^/api' а с остальными ключами не работает

Вот пример:

```
devServer: {
   proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'https://website1',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
      '^/api': {
        target: 'https://website2',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    }
 }
```